# If in CSS for navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css

I need to remove a line of code when the inline elements into a div goes on multiple rows, but I don't know how to do that

This page

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: black;
}
#nav {
    color: #fff;
    border: 4px solid white;
    background: #000;
    text-align: center;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    /*if goes on multiple rows, remove 'display:inline-block'*/
    display: inline-block;
}
li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 2.5px 6px;
}
li a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
#active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}
</style>
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li><a href="i" id="active">Home</a></li><li><a href="">Page1</a></li><li><a href="">Wow</a></li><li><a href="">Asdfgh</a></li><li><a href="">Test</a></li><li><a href="">CSS</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

When is resized, should be like this:
[image]

how can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry for the long code, but I was not able to use jsfiddle, however now I try to post here the link: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mFcEDDaF98

Comment: Just add a class to this <li> specifying that it has children ?

Comment: @Loenix what do you mean? Can you make an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`media query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

This will allow you to use specific CSS rules for specific screen width ranges.

So after you settle on a width you want the `li` items to appear this way, simply write

```
@media (max-width: <some number>px) {
  li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/mkarajohn/vb16d46j/**

Simply resize the result pane to see it in action.

Comment: That's very nice thanks! But doesn't exist a method where I shouldn't specify the number of pixels or where calculate that number automatically?

Comment: I'm afraid no, you have to specify explicit widths.